# How to mark a table row as selected?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an application in which I display a pretty large amount of data - 20k rows. Paging is done via the Frontend - the Backend is a mess and I don't have the time to touch or modify it.

I've build a table via ngFor in which I select a row with a click and save the rowdata into a temporary variable.

What I couldn't figure out is how to elegantly highlight a row and if I click on another row de-highlight the old and highlight the newly selected row.

One idea is to append a class to a selected row and style it via that directive. But if I want to deselect the right row I need to iterate through all 20k rows - which is pretty bad. Is there a better solution?

I'm working with angular cli and angular ngx bootstrap.

Comment: when you saying "Paging is done via the Frontend" you load all your 20K in the front, or you do it page by page ?

Comment: All in one - I know it is a pretty bad thing - but it is legacy code which is not supposed to be handled.

Comment: the response depends on your code, can you share it ?

Comment: I can't work with you if there isn't a sample code. But here's what I had in mind though, each of the row would have an id, so my advise is to clear the style from previous id and then highlight the one that's being clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I will provide a sample of code tomorrow because I need my workstation for it. Thanks for the hint as well  - I will wrap my head around it this evening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of @danielctw I found a solution.

In the table `ngFor` I´m doing the following:

```
[className]="selectedEntityID === entity.ID ? 'selected' : ''"
```

And in the CSS the following:

```
.some-table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: $colorpick-hover;
}
```

Maybe it is helpful for someone else,